# Reactjs - cookies do not persist only in production, with Firefox giving incorrect warning

Tags: node.js, reactjs, security, cookies, cross-domain

So, in my application I am setting a cookie as follows:

```
    this.cookies.set('session', sessionProperties, { 
            path: '/',
            expires: new Date(session.valid_until),
            secure: true,
            sameSite: 'none'
        });
```

By debugging, I can see the correct string being generated, ending in `SameSite=None; Secure`. I then see the .cookies object with the session object in it.

This occurs only on the production server - it works locally and on other test servers.

However, the browser then reports that no cookies exist at all, and Firefox complains that the session cookies will in the future not save because it is missing Secure - which is absurd since (1) it is already not being saved, and (2) it does have Secure set

- I have CORS set up correctly, allowing the correct origin domain and with Allow Credentials
- I am fetching with credentials: true
- It is HTTPS

I am out of ideas - I don't know why it is not being saved, or how to troubleshoot this further.

Please note that `secure:true` and `sameSite: 'none'` as well as `credentials: true` and non wildcard CORS are all troubleshooting steps taken while trying to fix this, and are not the cause since the issue predates them

The only thing I can see is that something between me and the server is causing cookies to fail.

What could cause this?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You mean that you set the cookie, you see the `Set-Cookie` header but the browser never returns the cookie in a `Cookie` header except in production where it works as expected? Where does CORS fit in all of this? What's the value on `session.valid_until`? Are you connecting to your site with `https`?

Comment: The cookie isn't part of the request the cookies just being set in JavaScript. The function to set the cookie appears to work but the browser simply fails to save the cookie. The cors stuff was just me grasping at straws

Comment: document.cookie is empty again as soon as the page is reloaded

Comment: Are you SETTING the cookie CLIENT-SIDE only and when you reload the page it is gone? In the most common use of sessions, cookies are SENT by the backend once a browser is authenticated and then PASSED BACK to the server on every request for identification. Is this what you're doing here? If so, check the headers in the communication. If you're only setting the cookie client-side with Javascript, then check the browser cookie store once you've set the cookie and verify that it is accepted BEFORE RELOAD. If it's not, then some of your parameters are probably off.

Comment: But since it's a client side only cookie why would the server it's run on affect this, it only seems to fail when run from this server specifically

Comment: If it's a client-side cookie, then let's just ignore the server part. As I said, if you set the cookie and then inspect the browser settings and the cookie is not set, then there is something wrong with how you set the cookie. Try to create a sandbox example where this problem shows.

Comment: NTP was failing on that server - so the cookie started it's like expired based on the session data sent by the server. Fixed NTP, all works again